# Password Protect HTML5 Offline Application Directory

Tags: javascript, authentication, html, offline

I have an HTML5 app which is capable of running offline.  However, I need to password protect the directory this app resides in to only allow access to authorized users.  Initially I was using a PHP login page which set a cookie (outside of the app directory) then redirected to the app directory.  The app (JavaScript) checks for the cookie and if it's there it lets the user run the app.  If not, it redirects them back out of the app directory.

The problem with this method is that all of the files in the directory are still accessible if referenced directly (which I don't want).  I do not want users to have to authenticate every time they hit the directory (it's a one-time authentication process; the cookie is there so that they never have to type their username/password again), and I also want to have a stylized login form (i.e. not using the default browser login box for http authentication).

Finally, because this is an offline HTML5 app, I can't include any PHP code in the app itself.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't sound like something you could do from Javascript. The script would need access to the file system to be able to restrict access to the folder, wouldn't it?

Unless this feature is exposed by the browser via a javascript API, I don't think it will be possible. It sounds like it would be a useful feature though.

Perhaps you could encrypt vital data, but apart from slowing down the application, I'm not sure what good it would do, since all the necessary keys would have to be stored locally as well...

Since the general rule of security on the web is that you can never ever rely on anything that happens client-side (e.g. in Javascript) without a double check on the server-side, this will of course pose a problem when the app is running offline and the server-side is not available :(

Looking at the "make Javascript redirect if the cookie exists" problem, unless I'm mistaken, it would be trivial for a malicious user to edit the Javascript, using for example Firebug, to redirect in any case.

EDIT: By the way, what level of security are you looking for? The "mom won't be able to accidentally access my account"-level (which it sounds like you already achieved), or the "no one, except maybe the NSA, should be able to hack it"-level?

Comment: I wish I could reply inline to each of your paragraphs, as you make some very good points. I'll do my best to address each. I agree that this ideally needs to be a browser API implementation that doesn't currently exist. That would be the best-case scenario, but just isn't available. As for encryption, the best scenario I've come up with here is to email the "public key" to the users so that they can "unlock" the app (i.e. decrypt it). Not the best scenario, but it at least adds an extra level of protection. ... (continued in next comment) ...

Comment: I've tried using http authentication, but it fails as soon as the user is offline (for obvious reasons), so in either that case or a PHP-based server-side authentication, it's just not an option. As for editing the JS via Firebug, I agree that's an issue. For this reason, in addition to the "public key" method (or as a replacement for - haven't quite decided whether or not to use that method yet) there are multiple levels of checks built in now (cookies, localStorage, etc.). Admittedly, a savvy user could still get around it, but it would require a lot of code dissection ...

Comment: And finally, re. level of security - I suppose I'd like somewhere in between. Let's say I'd prefer if StackOverflow users couldn't access files I didn't want them to (maybe that implies more secure than NSA - not sure ;) )

Comment: What it comes down to is that it's a paid app. The client doesn't want people to access it without paying for it. But they also understand the technical deficiencies, so are willing to go for a "best-case" scenario. I just want to make sure that I deliver that without leaving loopholes.